# Using WCF in MonoDevelop / MonoTouch: how to use the app.config file?

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have added a web reference to a WCF service in my MT project (using MonoDevelop 2.4.2 here).
I am trying to recycle the app.config file that is used by Visual Studio. I copied it over into my MT's root directory and specified "copy to output directory" in MonoDevelop. Still it does not work.
What is the correct way to use an app.config in MonoDevelop?

René

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use app.config files in Monotouch unfortunately. You have to create all the bindings yourself in code. In one of our projects, this is what we have done:

```
public static ServiceClient GetClient()
{
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,10);
    binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,10);
    binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,10);
    binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
    binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
    binding.AllowCookies = false;


    // snip - we set all the properties found in the serverside config file in code here

    EndPointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("https://www.domain.com/ServiceClient.svc");
    ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient(binding, endpointAddress);
    return client;
}
```

You need to go through and set EVERY property that is found in the server's app.config file, ensuring that the values match exactly, otherwise this won't work. 
(If I've misunderstood your question, then I do apologise!).

Comment: You got it right. That's what I did and I end up with another problem, as posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667030/make-this-wcf-client-code-work-on-mono-and-monotouch-on-the-mac

Answer (score -1):

I think you just need to properly name the .config file and place it in your output directory:

myapp.exe.config

I do not think MD does it automatically for you like VS does.

Comment: Is that case sensitive? Because I tried to name it "WCFTest.exe.config" and that did not work.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see this was MonoTouch.  The other answer is correct that MT does not support this.

Comment: Config is not necessary, in code also you can define all properties.